# Downloading from MongDB GridFS stops working properly after a certain number of attempts to download

Tags: node.js, mongodb, download, gridfs

I want to download a file from my MongoDB database. I've found using a GridFS bucket's openDownloadStream works when you pipe it to Node's fs createWriteStream then on it's 'finish' you send that data to the client side for download using res download. My problem is that after a few attempts at downloading files my timeout safety cushion fails and the client can't find the file in time the browser then gives an empty response error. However, after a few seconds the file does eventually download.

I'm integrating a mongoDB into an existing server that had already had download functionality. Before, the files were stored in the project's file system, now they are in MongoDB. I've tried piping to different places with no luck.

```
// Router's Download Logic
router.get("/download", function(req, res) {
  setTimeout(download, 2000);
  function download() {
      var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(localDatabase())
      bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(file)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file))
          .on('error', function(error) {
            assert.ifError(error)
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            console.log(`Downloaded ${file}`)
            res.download(file)
            fs.access(file, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              }
              else {
                fs.unlinkSync(file)
              }
            })
          })
  }
});
```

I expect for the file to download after that 2 second window giving the functions enough time to run. What I'm getting is an Empty Response Error after about 3 attempts downloading. I eventually get the file but it seems like the more I download in one server instance the longer it takes to download -> pipe -> createWriteStream.

EDIT: The problem comes from the unlink. I changed the path to go to a TEMP folder but I don't want to store those files in there forever. I also don't want to unlink them in the same algorithm as downloading them as that's what caused the issue. Any advice on this would really help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the edit, the problem was calling the unlink at virtually the same time as the res.download, this caused the hang ups. To avoid that small window I added a setTimeout to the remove file function. A possible bug is when you download two files too fast, to avoid this I am putting an alert to let the user know to wait for the download to finish before trying to downloading again.

```
router.get("/download", function(req, res) {
  setTimeout(download, 1000);
  function download(callback) {
      var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(localDatabase())
      bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(file)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('private/TEMP/' + file))
          .on('error', function(error) {
            assert.ifError(err)
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            res.download('private/TEMP/' + file)
            console.log(`Downloaded ${file}`)
            setTimeout(removeFile, 1200)
          })

  }
  function removeFile() {
    fs.access('private/TEMP/' + file, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      else {
        fs.unlinkSync('private/TEMP/' + file)
      }
    })
  }
});
```